# can i lock iPhone native app from my app?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to lock native apps from my app.

it is possible or not.

Please suggest me.

Comment: What do you mean by "**lock** apps from my app"? You want to prevent the user to switch to another app other than your own? (If so, yes it is possible)

Comment: @AliSoftware "lock" mean set a passcode.

Comment: So you want to ask for a passcode if the user tries to launch your application (which is possible, too)? Or if the user tries to exit your application? Please be more specific in your question, it is **very** unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible, You app runs in a sandbox and can't manipulate any thing outside that sandbox.